# Connected via Ethernet LAN Network with Static IP address and WiFi, unable to connect to the internet via WiFi

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and connected to a local device with IP 192.168.50.64, so I set the static IP of the computer to 192.168.50.10 to access the secondary device's locally hosted website. This works.

But I am unable to access the internet at all (cannot pull from git or ping 8.8.8.8 as it attempts the pings from the ethernet side.) I can ssh into the ubuntu machine, via the WiFi, so there is some connection that allows that.

I have disabled the Ethernet connection on the Ubuntu machine using `sudo ifdown eth0`, which works according to `nmcli dev status`. Still not able to access the internet though.

Comment: Please [edit] your Question and show us `ip link;ip route;service NetworkManager status`. Note: `ifup` and `ifdown` have been obsoleted by `nmcli`. Read `man ip ip-link ip-route service nmcli ifup``